# When using Mockito verify method `times` got null

Tags: java, mockito

When I trying to use Mockito verify to test extral call times of testMethod(indeed this method is just execute 2 times), but I got following message.

```
verify(XXXXXXX, times(2)).testMethod(any(XXXXXX.class))
|      |          |         |        |        |
|      |          |         null    null      class XXXXXX
|      |          Wanted invocations count: 2
|      Mock for XXXXXXX, hashCode: 292294397
Mock for XXXXXXX, hashCode: 292294397
```

If I change the times to 1, and the error message is:

```
verify(XXXXXXX, times(1)).testMethod(any(XXXXXX.class))
|      |          |         |     |         |
|      |          |         |     null      class XXX
|      |          |         org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
|      |          |         XXX.XXXX(
|      |          |             <any XXX>
|      |          |         );
|      |          |         Wanted 1 time:
|      |          |         -> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|      |          |         But was 2 times:
|      |          |         -> at XXXX.XXX(XXX.java:129)
|      |          |         -> at XXXXX.XXX(XXX.java:129)
|      |          |          
|      |          |         
|      |          Wanted invocations count: 1
```

Does anybody have met this problem before?

Comment: Is it actually a problem? To me it just looks like a debug or informational message from Mockito. Do you get an exception or error in the first case?

Comment: I didn't get any exception in the first case. But the method is called 2 times, and the test case should be passed, while it just told me that `Condition not satisfied`. When I change the `times(2)` to `times(1)`, the error message is just like the second case.

Comment: No, I didn't Mock the native/system class.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `|| true` helped me resolve similar issue:

```
verify(mock, times(2)).methodName(captor.capture()) || true
```

Comment: This is obviously only going to compile without error if `methodName` returns `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `verify(XXXXXXX, times(2)).testMethod(any(XXXXXX.class))` right after the testing. The general usage pattern in Mockito is:

- when(mock.doSomething()).then()
- doTheThingYouAreTesting()
- verify(mock).doSomething()

If you're using Spock in your tests, add the `verify` statement within the same block without separating it from labels like `then` or `and`. Example:

```
given:
...something

when:
doTheThingYouAreTesting()
verify(mock).doSomething()

then:
...something
```